# Enviar video en directo webcam a través de sockets c++

Tags: c++, socket, opencv, networking

Quiero hacer un programa que envíe lo que graba la webcam(desde el ordenador del cliente) a otro ordenador(el servidor). He creado un programa de networking que funcionaba bien, pero cuando trato de pasar lo que graba la cámara me da un error en la parte del servidor.

El error es `La expresión debe tener un valor constante. El valor de la variable "imgSize" no se puede usar como una constante.` Este error da en la línea de `uchar sockData[imgSize];`.

El código es...

```
        int n,bytes = 0, IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH;
        int imgSize;
        char buffer[256];
        Mat img;

        IM_HEIGHT = FRAME_HEIGHT;
        IM_WIDTH = FRAME_WIDTH;
        img = Mat::zeros(FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH, CV_8UC3);

        imgSize = img.total() * img.elemSize();
        uchar sockData[imgSize];

        for (int i = 0;i < imgSize;i += bytes)
            if ((bytes = recv(newConnection, sockData + i, imgSize - i, 0)) == -1) return 1;

        int ptr = 0;

        for (int i = 0;i < img.rows;++i)
            for (int j = 0;j < img.cols;++j)
            {
                img.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = Vec3b(sockData[ptr + 0], sockData[ptr + 1], sockData[ptr + 2]);
                ptr = ptr + 3;
            }

        namedWindow("Server", 1);// Create a window for display.
        imshow("Server", img);
        char key = waitKey(30);
        bool running = key;
        //esc
        if (key == 27) running = false;
```

(Este código es parte del servidor y está escrito después de haber establecido la conxión).

He tratado de declararlo como constante, pero entonces da otro error en el que pone `imgSize debe tener un valor L modificable`.

No sé que hacer y hay muy poca información en google sobre este tema. Estoy utilizando Windows 10, opencv 4.5.2 y visual studio 19. Toda ayuda será agradecida, por poco que sea.

Comment: Parece que deberás usar para sockData, una matriz de longitud variable, como por ejemplo usando el "template" std:vector

Comment: Si quieres  que sockData  se sea un arreglo con un tamaño calculado en tiempo de ejecución los  tienes que convertir en un  puntero:  uchar * sockData = new  uchar[imgSize), Luego  lo utilizas con notación de arreglo sockData[ptr + 0]

Comment: Si lo pones como constante te acepta la definición  pero ya no te acepta cuando le quieres asignar un valor:  imgSize = img.total() * img.elemSize(); porque una constante no la puedes modificar aunque hay  una forma de hacerlo pero no es recomendable

Comment: Tienes que usar `std::vector`, o `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.